# Will inhabitants of Jannah still learn?

Tags: jannah

Will they learn things in jannah like for library or wanting to know histroy of things happen in earth and known prophets and unkown prophet's and things like secret of universe or why Allah created this and that.

Comment: If they want to yes, because in Jannah you will get what you want

Answer (score 1):

I highly believe that there will be a lot of things to learn and I doubt that learning the wisdom of Allah will ever have an end.

قُل لَّوْ كَانَ الْبَحْرُ مِدَادًا لِّكَلِمَاتِ رَبِّي لَنَفِدَ الْبَحْرُ قَبْلَ أَن تَنفَدَ كَلِمَاتُ رَبِّي وَلَوْ جِئْنَا بِمِثْلِهِ مَدَدًا - 18:109
"Say, "If the sea were ink for [writing] the words of my Lord, the sea
would be exhausted before the words of my Lord were exhausted, even if
We brought the like of it as a supplement."

This is also a reference to ALLAH'S wisdom and knowledge that has no end glory be to Him.